# Symfony 4, Login, how debug the error 'Invalid credentials'?

Tags: php, symfony, session, authentication, symfony4

From symfony 4, I would like create a simple authentication form. I created a User class (the identifier is the email field, not the 'Username', I created a class controller and configured the security.yml file.

I created some users with this static method : (for tests, password by default is 'test')

```
class User implements \Serializable, UserInterface
{
// ...
  public static function new_alea($email, $isActive = false, $password="test"){
    $instance = new self();
    $instance->isActive = $isActive;
    $instance->email = $email;

    $brypt = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(4);
    $instance->password = $brypt->encodePassword($password, null);

    return $instance;
  }
// ...
}
```

Its work, there are some user in my database with encrypted passwords.

But when I go to the form page and try to login (fill email/password fields and click on the submit button), I get the error "Invalid credentials."

[image]

What this error means ? How/where do I debug my code for find why this error occurs ?

Below, mains part of my code, maybe you'll see an error I didn't see :

the security.yaml file :

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
    providers:
        my_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        main:
            provider: my_db_provider
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
    role_hierarchy:
        # ...
```

the User Entity Class :

```
class User implements \Serializable, UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    private $plainPassword;

    public static function new_alea($email, $isActive = false, $password="coucou"){
        $instance = new self();
        $instance->isActive = $isActive;
        $instance->email = $email;

        $brypt = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(4);
        $instance->password = $brypt->encodePassword($password, null);

        return $instance;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials() {
        $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function serialize() {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->email,
            $this->password,
        ));
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized) {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->email,
            $this->password,
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    public function getRoles() {
        return array('ROLE_ADMIN');
    }

    public function getPassword() {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword($password) {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function getUsername() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setUsername($email) {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getPlainPassword() {
        return $this->plainPassword;
    }

    public function setPlainPassword($plainPassword): void {
        $this->plainPassword = $plainPassword;
    }

    // and others getters/setters
```

the login Controller :

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function login(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authUtils)
    {
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $email = $authUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('frontend/log/login.html.twig', array(
            'email' => $email,
            'error' => $error,
        ));
    }
}
```

And the template login.html.twig file :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

    {% if error %}
        <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="_email" value="{{ email }}" />

        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

        {#
            If you want to control the URL the user
            is redirected to on success (more details below)
            <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account" />
        #}

        <button type="submit">login</button>
    </form>

{% endblock body %}
```

Comment: In the ... section of User are you implementing all the UserInterface methods?  Especially getUsername()?

Comment: Yes, you can see the getUsername() in my paste :)

Comment: Okay.  Typically you would want to use the actual password encoder to encode your password.  This will ensure that you are using the exact same options as Symfony does.  For now run "php bin/console security:encode-password test" and see if you get the same encoded password as your method does.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) When I run your command (with password 'test'), I get the encoded password and the encoder used (Encoder used : Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\BCryptPasswordEncoder"). Then I copy/paste  the encoded password in the user table in one user (via phpmyadmin). And I tried to login with this user from my login page, I get yet the "Invalid credentials." messsage :/

Comment: Hmmm.  Under security: add "hide_user_not_found:  false" That will change the message to either "user not found" or "invalid password".  This will verify the problem is with the password and narrow things down a bit.

Comment: By the way, if you look at the [Security Config Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#full-default-configuration) you will see that the bcrypt encoder has a default cost of 13.  That could also be the problem. [bcrypt encoder details](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#using-the-bcrypt-password-encoder)

Comment: I added "hide_user_not_found: false" and indeed ! I got the message "user not found" (I tried with email, with id table..ever the same message). But I don't see where is my mistake..

Comment: Ah ha!  In your form, name="_email" should be name="_username" or else be overridden under form_login.

Comment: Hannnn ! thank you ! that solves my problem . Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi i get the same problem today, for me it was i put a restriction of the number of caracter in my string password. So the password was wrong because the encode took too many caracter. So i delete the limit of caracter and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use two router paths with the same function name and different label name so that it will moves to your login path when username and password is correct. It will moves to another path when you have invalid password or username.

EXAMPLE:

```
index:
 path: /
 controller: App\Controller\DefaultController::login

login:
  path: /login
  controller: App\Controller\DefaultController::login
```

Answer (score 0):

just output `{{ error }}` below the "**frontend**" error message to get the full stacktrace etc...

Answer (score 0):

In your login template, add a `{{ dump(error) }}`. It includes the real error message (which will often suffice), and the whole stack trace if needed. And is more nicely formatted than just `{{ error }}` :

```
{% if error %}
    {{  dump(error) }}
    <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I meet a similar problem, I solved by changing my passwords from plain text into encoded version.

```
# I create users by fixtures
$user->setEmail('admin@admin');
$user->setPassword('admin'); // Wrong

$user->setPassword($this->passwordEncoder->encodePassword(
    $user,
    'admin'
)); // Correct
```

Official Ref: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#accessing-services-from-the-fixtures